# Can I ask questions about political ideologies and forms of governments?

Tags: support, allowed-topics

Are questions about political ideologies and forms of government considered on-topic for Philosophy.SE?

Comment: Yes, absolutely; philosophy of politics is certainly on point here. As always try to keep it as specific and serious as possible and provide as much theoretical context as you can -- for instance, "what is liberalism?" would not be as constructive as, say, "which political philosophers argued for proposition x (and how/why/what are the most significant responses)?"

Comment: @Joseph: What about questions like "What is the difference between X and Y?" where X and Y are something like Liberalism, Libertariansim, Republicanism, .. etc. Also I wanted to ask about the name of ideologies corresponding to certain beliefs and the relation between ideologies and ethics and religion. Are questions like this considered on topic?

Comment: Questions of this nature are on-topic if formulated clearly as questions about philosophy -- I might suggest framing these as asking after the central points of the debate (most significant issues of contention) between two politico-philosophical perspectives.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If it is philosophical in nature and has a real answer, definitely!

Comment: What about the examples I mentioned in my comment above? I am sorry I cannot judge what is "philosophical in nature" about politics because I am an engineer and I do not have the sufficient educational background.

Comment: Generally, as long as you avoid asking questions which will generate lots of speculation, and narrow them down so they are answerable without writing a whole novel, you should be fine. By "Philosophical in nature" I just meant that questions should generally be about finding out the basic truths and principles about the things around us using logic and reason. I.E. it would fall under a topic of philosophy.

Answer (score 3):

Questions about politics—with the qualification that it is a philosophical question—are very welcome here.

You shouldn't worry *too* much about whether your question(s) are philosophical enough. If you're unsure, you can either:

1. Just try them out by asking them on the site, and we will give feedback one way or the other; or
2. You can post a question here on Meta explaining your proposed question, and soliciting advice on whether it would be on topic. Even if it's not on topic as you've currently formulated it, I'm sure someone can help you modify the question so that it *is* well suited for the site.